# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in includes\common.inc on line 3022

Tags: 7

I have upgraded *Drupal 6* to latest version `6.36` and *PHP* to `5.6`. I am getting *Fatal error* saying;

> Unsupported operand type while accessing `admin/content/node`.

Which is actually nothing but simple addition of an array to variable;

`$elements += array('#title' => NULL, '#description' => NULL);`

Any help?

Comment: The $elements variable probably contains an array element that the key does not start with a hash sign and the value is scalar.

Comment: Why haven't you read Drupal's system requirements page before doing it? I used to be like that, too. "Read instructions... when all else fails". It's pretty stupid thing in the long run, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

From official [system requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements):

> PHP 5.3.x and higher may produce errors or unexpected behavior

Thus, sadly, what you are seeing is pretty much "expected" unexpected behaviour. Drop back to PHP 5.2.x (x ≥ 5) or upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8 for a full fix.

If you want to only fix this one, consider what [AyeshK](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1899/ayeshk) wrote in [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169663/fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types-in-includes-common-inc-on-line-3022#comment203556_169663):

> The `$elements` variable probably contains an array element that the key does not start with a hash sign and the value is scalar.

There is a lot of things about array operators. [Comments under PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) shows that many things are far from obvious. Also, it changed a bit from version to version. Have you tested if `$elements` is an array in the first place? *"Simply"* add tests to make sure if operand is still valid, and provide a fallback if it isn't (recreate original behaviour) and you will be good to go.